# My question is closed almost one year after being asked

Tags: discussion

Because someone wrote a very poor and totally unnecessary 6th answer to one of my questions [I asked one year ago](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11575/why-is-the-eu-wishing-to-punish-the-uk-instead-of-listening-their-detractors-and/19625#19625), it brought it up to the stream attention (something even I didn't want !) and my question got a rain of downvotes and close votes **that didn't happen back then when I asked**.

If this question deserved to be closed, **then it deserved it to be closed right away, not one year later, because someone wrote a poor answer. *I* am being punished because of *his* answer**

Comment: I don't (yet) have an opinion whether this question should be closed, but I do know that the age of the question is irrelevant. Sometimes mistakes are made and questions "slip through", or the community and/or the rules change. Also, if your goal is to get this question re-opened you may get better responses if your question is framed more constructively (e.g. "how can I rephrase my question to be on-topic?"), or at the very least be an actual question ("why is this considered off-topic?"), rather than a statement ("I am being punished for a poor answer") which comes off a bit like a rant

Comment: Indeed, but that statement is the truth. Without that answer, the question wouldn't have been noticed this year and wouldn't have been neither downvoted nor closed. This is completely illogical and I consider it a flaw/bug in this platform. (Regardless of my question itself)

Comment: Sorry but that's dumb. If my question was horrible, it should have been down-voted or closed when it was asked, last year. The fact it had already a few successful answers proves it's answerable. **I don't see how it makes any sense to close questions long after they're asked and answered.**

Comment: Questions are bumped up when new answers are added so that they can be voted on. Sometimes old questions get really bad answers, and sometimes really great ones. I have personally answered several questions from 3+ years ago, and had the question *not* been bumped then those answers would have gone unnoticed. `I don't see how it makes any sense to close questions long after they're asked and answered`: to prevent new (bad) answers from being added. Bad questions tend to attract bad answers (I am not saying this question is bad, but this is the reason questions can be closed regardless of age).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Shouldn't the bad answer just be flagged, and not the entire question?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

Questions and answers don't go away on their own, even after after several years.

A question getting new interest and new votes after a period of time is all part of the game.  Peoples' understanding of the subject matter changes, new answers get posted, site standards evolve, and numerous people come to the question from google and read it long after it's settled down.